# Windows containers are not being scheduled on GKE Cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, windows-container

I am trying to schedule windows container on GKE node. I have added a separate windows node pool with image type **Windows long term servicing channel with containerd (windows_ltsc_containerd)**. When I try to deploy the windows container on this node pool, I am getting this error. Can someone please guide me what I am missing here. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Error Message:

```
`message: >-
        admission webhook "windows.common-webhooks.networking.gke.io" denied the
        request: [spec.volumes[3].volumeSource.emptyDir.medium: Unsupported
        value: "Memory": supported values: "\"\" (empty string indicates disk
        for Windows)", spec.initContainers[0].securityContext: Invalid value:
        v1.SecurityContext{Capabilities:(*v1.Capabilities)(0xc00096ad80),
        Privileged:(*bool)(0xc000bdfc13),
        SELinuxOptions:(*v1.SELinuxOptions)(nil),
        WindowsOptions:(*v1.WindowsSecurityContextOptions)(nil),
        RunAsUser:(*int64)(0xc000bdfc18), RunAsGroup:(*int64)(0xc000bdfc20),
        RunAsNonRoot:(*bool)(0xc000bdfc28),
        ReadOnlyRootFilesystem:(*bool)(0xc000bdfc29),
        AllowPrivilegeEscalation:(*bool)(0xc000bdfc2a),
        ProcMount:(*v1.ProcMountType)(nil),
        SeccompProfile:(*v1.SeccompProfile)(nil)}: Windows does not support this
        field. Note that defaults may be allowed for compatibility.,
        spec.containers[1].securityContext: Invalid value:
        v1.SecurityContext{Capabilities:(*v1.Capabilities)(0xc00096ae10),
        Privileged:(*bool)(0xc000bdfe7f),
        SELinuxOptions:(*v1.SELinuxOptions)(nil),
        WindowsOptions:(*v1.WindowsSecurityContextOptions)(nil),
        RunAsUser:(*int64)(0xc000bdfe90), RunAsGroup:(*int64)(0xc000bdfea0),
        RunAsNonRoot:(*bool)(0xc000bdfeac),
        ReadOnlyRootFilesystem:(*bool)(0xc000bdfead),
        AllowPrivilegeEscalation:(*bool)(0xc000bdfeae),
        ProcMount:(*v1.ProcMountType)(nil),
        SeccompProfile:(*v1.SeccompProfile)(nil)}: Windows does not support this
        field. Note that defaults may be allowed for compatibility.]`
```

Dockerfile:

```
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build
# set the working directory inside compilation container to c:\app
WORKDIR /app
 
# copy everything from solution dir into the c:\app
COPY . .
# restore nuget packages
RUN nuget restore -PackagesDirectory "Mycompany.InvoiceCloud.Web/"

RUN msbuild "Mycompany.InvoiceCloud.Web/Mycompany.InvoiceCloud.Web.csproj" /v:diag
 
# start with new base image for running asp.net apps (which contains IIS)
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8 AS runtime

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

COPY --from=build /app/Mycompany.InvoiceCloud.Web/bin .`
```

Deployment File:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dev-invoicecloud-web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dev-invoicecloud-web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dev-invoicecloud-web
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: windows
      containers:
        - name: dev-invoicecloud-web
          image: gcr.io/invoicecloudweb:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

Windows containers are not being scheduled on GKE Cluster

Answer (score 0):

Is there something else being deployed with this? Where does the error message comes from? It seems there's something wrong with the volume mount for Windows, but I'm not sure where that is coming from as it is on your spec.

Comment: The error I have attached is coming from namespace events.

Comment: got it. What shows up when you check the pod/deployment? Have you run kubectl describe pod <pod id>?

Comment: As sson I run my deployment I start getting the error pasted above. No pod is spun up and this error actually rejects the deployment to be scheduled on windows node.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on the specification and cluster config? It seems there's something you're setting that is not supported on GKE for Windows.

Comment: This is my cluster version. What else you need. About window node all information is provided in question.
 kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.23.1
Server Version: v1.23.12-gke.1600

Comment: I honestly don't know where to look into as you're not even getting pods scheduled. If you did, we could look into the events using "kubectl describe pod". This log doesn't say much in terms on where to look into. One thing you can try is to run "kubectl describe deployment dev-invoicecloud-web" This will show the status and information about the deployment.